# In a PyCharm debugging session, how to move the cursor to to current line that is being executed?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I'm new with PyCharm. In a debugging session, the current line that is being executed is highlighted. I may look around in the code and lost where I am. Is there a quick way to go to the current line that is being executed?

BTW, I added other JetBrains IDE tags it's because I think they may have similar shortcuts or similar way to solve the problem. You are freely to remove them if you think it's not proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run | Show Execution Point

(The action has a keyboard shortcut which depends on the keymap that you're using; the shortcut is shown in the menu.)

Comment: You mean "Run" in the toolbar. In my case with PyCharm Professional is toolbar > Run > Debugging actions > Show execution point.